# Dynamic Gridview combination of 3 different table from SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

There are too many data that need to combine together into one gridview to show summary of the data. I have 3 separate table that I need to combine and show in a summary module.

**Table A** (Table that contain data user submit)

```
ID   Name 
001  Jackson Peter
```

**Table B** (Table contain data that need to get thru level approval)

```
ID   Level   Approval
001  1       Open
001  2       Awaiting
```

**Table C** (Table that contain level for each module)

```
Module_ID      Level    PersonInCharge
ModulePayment  1        FinancePIC
ModulePayment  2        AdminPIC
```

**RESULT I WANTED**

```
ID  Name            FinancePIC   AdminPic
001 Jackson Peter   Open         Awaiting
```

Is that possible to combine it all together into one? 
I have tried my way of doing it, but some how i not able to get table B to show in my gridview. Is there something that i missing ?
While pageload I will call function to get the Table C by using for loop and together with boundfield. In the meantime, it will get the binddata of Table A inner join with Table B.

**BindData**

```
Private Sub getSummary()
        Dim strSQL As String
        Dim params As New Hashtable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim strWhere As String = ""

        Try

            params.Clear()

            strSQL = " Select *  FROM TableA  " & _
                " inner join TableB " & _
                " on TableA.ID = TableB.ID order by TableA.ID desc "

            common.execReader(strSQL, params, dt, common.txn)

            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Gridview.Controls.Clear()
                Gridview.DataSource = dt
                Gridview.DataBind()
            End If


        Catch ex As Exception
            Me.lblUnsucces.Text = ex.Message
        End Try
    End Sub
```

**Gridview**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" DataKeyNames="ID" PageSize="20" TabIndex="-1" Width="100%" GridLines="None" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#405467" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="white" AllowSorting="true">
                                         <Columns>
                                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Selection">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="UpdateData" Height="16px" ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.gif" />
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteData" Height="16px" ImageUrl="~/Images/delete_icon.gif" OnClientClick="javacsrip:if(confirm('Are you sure?')==false) return false;" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Doc No" >
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Desccription">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name")%>'></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                    </Columns>

                                        <FooterStyle CssClass="gridFooter" />
                                        <PagerStyle CssClass="gridPager" />
                                        <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="gridSelected" />
                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridHeader" />
                                        <EditRowStyle CssClass="gridEdit" />
                                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridAlternatingItem" />
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Just a few hints.Name your fields you want in your sql like "SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, ......  FROM..." Use <%# Bind("name")%>' for binding data in your Grid.

Comment: i want it to be dynamic and if i fit the fields it will be no more dynamic. it will change after a few months and i do not want the user to touch the table. Maybe the person inchange will be change to different level. According to which section or module user enter.